# jquery drag element get stick to the mouse on click of the element in chrome

Tags: jquery, events, click, draggable

jQuery drag element gets stuck to the mouse on click of the element in chrome.

What do I need to do?

Comment: what about to accept some answers?

Comment: What you need to do i elaborate on when the problem occures.